# Wordpress Database Optimisation for large Sites

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb, query-optimization

I have a large Wordpress site with 170.000 users and a lot of daily page views.
I just tuned all MySQL indexes based on several comments but actually in my slow logs the SELECT distinct wp_usermeta.meta_key FROM wp_usermeta; takes around 3 seconds.
Server Hardware is: Dedicated Server with AMD Epyc 64 Cores, 128Gb DDR4, 2x480 NVMe SSD.

DB Server is MariaDB newest Version and config is (only innoDB tables):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 64G
innodb_log_file_size = 16G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 16
innodb_io_capacity = 5000
max_binlog_size = 200M
max_connections = 250
wait_timeout = 28700
interactive_timeout = 28700
join_buffer_size = 128M
expire_logs_days = 3
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time = 1
sql-mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

tmp_table_size = 256M
max_heap_table_size = 256M
table_definition_cache = 500
sort_buffer_size = 24M
key_buffer_size = 32M
performance_schema = on
```

Maybe someone has some suggestions

Comment: Is your wp_usermeta.meta_key an indexed column? Hopefully it is defined as unique.

Comment: yes meta_key is already indexed

Comment: Please post the LAST 100 lines of your slow query log for analysis.

Comment: since the slow is full of nearly the same query it is 99% of:

# Time: 220204 21:23:29
# User@Host: xxxx[xxxxx] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 3199142  Schema: xxxx  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 3.318315  Lock_time: 0.000025  Rows_sent: 172845  Rows_examined: 7464986
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 2248476
SET timestamp=1644006209;
SELECT distinct wp_usermeta.meta_key FROM wp_usermeta;

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
top -H -p PID   for cpu usage 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/KpdNYB2i

Comment: Pastebin for Global Vars: https://pastebin.com/EAv4UBgw

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of:  very helpful OS information, includes - top -H -p PID for per cpu usage   for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.  Thanks for quick posting of your data.  Analysis can begin.  Would you be OPPOSED to using Query Cache for this specific query that is most frequently listed in SlowQueryLog?  DEMAND mode?

Comment: we are using Redis Object Caching with Wordpress Plugin

Comment: What time zone are you in?  We are in UTC -6 hrs - USA Central Time zone.  View profile for contact info and have a GREAT weekend.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_usermeta`, the size of that table, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: I don't understand why WP would need a list of all the 172K keys:  `SELECT distinct wp_usermeta.meta_key FROM wp_usermeta;`.  And why does each "user" have 40-50 entries in that table?  My first guess is that WP is doing something that is fine for a small system but brain-dead for your size of system.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the output from that query.  I'm having trouble understanding why each "user" might have is own unique "key".  (Note: 170K users vs 172K "Rows_sent" -- or is that just a coincidence??)

Comment: wp_usermeta has 7.6M Rows in total with 690MB , Each User/Id has 49 Rows and there are actually 800 new users/registrations each day. Rows per User are mostly based on Adress, DOB, Name etc... so personal data also keeping track of some balance and accounting stats. Also query cache might not work since nearly every minute the wp_usermeta is beeing updated e.g. "last_login" or new entries with registration data... 800 per day = 0,5 reg's per minute

Comment: Even 0.5 per second would not be "busy".  100/second is when it begins to get exciting.

Comment: Sorry, but WP is the "problem".  49 rows instead of 1 row is an example of where WP's schema design is not well suited for some of the applications it is used for.  That 1 row could have 49 columns or 1 JSON column or some combination of them.  I have glanced over the STATUS/VARIABLES -- nothing is significantly 'wrong'.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_usermeta`  and your list of plugins.  That way we'll know exactly how you've indexed your table and we'll know what software might be causing trouble.

Comment: I just released a new WordPress plugin intended to handle large numbers of registered users more scalably than WordPress code: https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-users-for-speed/   It might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Of the 49 'values' that are associated with each user, how many are used in a `WHERE` or `ORDER BY`?  I suspect only a few.

Here's a way to work around WP's abuse of the "Entity-Attribute-Value" design pattern.

Let's say, a,b,c are useful for filtering and/or ordering.  And the other 46 values are simply saved for displaying later.  Have 4 rows, not 49 rows in usermeta for each user.  3 rows would be for a,b,c; the rest for a JSON string of the rest of the stuff.

Then have the application aware of the JSON and code accordingly.

This change would necessitate rebuilding `wp_usermeta`.  46 rows per user would be gathered together and rearranged into a single meta row with a moderately large JSON string (in `meta_value`).  That might not shrink the table much, but it would make it faster to use.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.ini [mysqld] section to enable DEMAND query cache utilization.

```
query_cache_min_res_unit=512  # from 4096 to enable higher density of results
query_cache_size=50M  # from 1M to increase capacity 
query_cache_limit=6M  # from 1M target result for identified query is above 2M
query_cache_type=2  # from OFF to support DEMAND (SELECT SQL_CACHE ...)
net_buffer_length=96K  # from 16K to reduce packet in/out count
```

We should probably SKYPE TALK later today before making any changes.
In a few hours (3-4), I will check in.

Comment: @Peter Maarst    Will check in occcasionally next few days.

Comment: Be aware that the QC has been removed from MySQL 8.0 and is not handled by any(?) Clustering topology.  For that reason, I look for solutions that don't involve the QC.

Comment: @RickJames MariaDB continues to support Query Cache.  Sometimes it can be leveraged to the customer's advantage.  This may be one of those cases. Thanks, Wilson

Answer (score 0):

```
Analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES:
```

**Observations:**

- Version: 10.6.5-MariaDB-1:10.6.5+maria~bullseye-log
- 128 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 1d 02:48:55
- 384 QPS

**The More Important Issues:**

*I do not see any items that seem critical to help with the problem you are having.*

**Details and other observations:**

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,536`
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( innodb_io_capacity_max ) = 10,000` -- When urgently flushing, use this many IOPs.
-- Reads could be slugghish or spiky.

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 2,787,201 / 4145152 = 67.2%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 68719476736) is bigger than necessary?

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data / innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 22,248,669,184 / 65536M = 32.4%` -- Percent of buffer pool taken up by data
-- A small percent *may* indicate that the buffer_pool is unnecessarily big.

`( Innodb_log_writes ) = 5,298,275 / 96535 = 55 /sec`

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 96,535 / 60 * 16384M / 6560327680 = 4,213` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, innodb_log_file_size can be changed dynamically; I don't know about MariaDB.  Be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size (now 17179869184). (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( Innodb_row_lock_waits ) = 83,931 / 96535 = 0.87 /sec` -- How often there is a delay in getting a row lock.
-- May be caused by complex queries that could be optimized.

`( Innodb_row_lock_waits/Innodb_rows_inserted ) = 83,931/1560067 = 5.4%` -- Frequency of having to wait for a row.

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( join_buffer_size * Max_used_connections ) = (128M * 127) / 131072M = 12.4%` -- (A metric for pondering the size of join_buffer_size.)
-- join_buffer_size (now 134217728) should probably be shrunk to avoid running out of RAM.

`( (Com_show_create_table + Com_show_fields) / Questions ) = (66 + 1370563) / 37103211 = 3.7%` -- Naughty framework -- spending a lot of effort rediscovering the schema.
-- Complain to the 3rd party vendor.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( Created_tmp_tables ) = 2,088,713 / 96535 = 22 /sec` -- Frequency of creating "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables ) = 1,751,146 / 96535 = 18 /sec` -- Frequency of creating *disk* "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs
-- increase tmp_table_size (now 268435456) and max_heap_table_size (now 268435456).
Check the rules for temp tables on when MEMORY is used instead of MyISAM. Perhaps minor schema or query changes can avoid MyISAM.
Better indexes and reformulation of queries are more likely to help.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Questions ) = 1,751,146 / 37103211 = 4.7%` -- Pct of queries that needed on-disk tmp table.
-- Better indexes / No blobs / etc.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Created_tmp_tables ) = 1,751,146 / 2088713 = 83.8%` -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- Maybe increase tmp_table_size (now 268435456) and max_heap_table_size (now 268435456); improve indexes; avoid blobs, etc.

`( Handler_read_rnd_next ) = 104,164,660,719 / 96535 = 1079035 /sec` -- High if lots of table scans
-- possibly inadequate keys

`( (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) / Com_commit ) = (1561842 + 4652536 + 13886 + 42) / 352 = 17,694` -- Statements per Commit (assuming all InnoDB)
-- High: long transactions strain various things.

`( Com_insert + Com_delete + Com_delete_multi + Com_replace + Com_update + Com_update_multi ) = (1561842 + 13886 + 0 + 42 + 4652536 + 794) / 96535 = 65 /sec` -- writes/sec
-- 50 writes/sec + log flushes will probably max out I/O write capacity of HDD drives

`( ( Com_stmt_prepare - Com_stmt_close ) / ( Com_stmt_prepare + Com_stmt_close ) ) = ( 2208251 - 1415 ) / ( 2208251 + 1415 ) = 99.9%` -- Are you closing your prepared statements?
-- Add Closes.

`( Com_stmt_prepare - Com_stmt_close ) = 2,208,251 - 1415 = 2.21e+6` -- How many prepared statements have not been closed.
-- CLOSE prepared statements

`( Com_stmt_close / Com_stmt_prepare ) = 1,415 / 2208251 = 0.06%` -- Prepared statements should be Closed.
-- Check whether all Prepared statements are "Closed".

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = MIXED` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED.
-- ROW is preferred by 5.7 (10.3)

`( Syncs ) = 5,727,396 / 96535 = 59 /sec` -- Sync to disk for binlog.

`( Com_change_db ) = 1,168,504 / 96535 = 12 /sec` -- Probably comes from USE statements.
-- Consider connecting with DB, using db.tbl syntax, eliminating spurious USE statements, etc.

`( Connections ) = 3,377,949 / 96535 = 35 /sec` -- Connections
-- Increase wait_timeout (now 28700); use pooling?

`( thread_cache_size / Max_used_connections ) = 250 / 127 = 196.9%`
-- There is no advantage in having the thread cache bigger than your likely number of connections. Wasting space is the disadvantage.

`( thread_pool_size ) = 64` -- Number of 'thread groups'. Limits how many treads can be executing at once. Probably should not be much bigger than the number of CPUs.
-- Don't set much higher than the number of CPU cores.

You have the Query Cache half-off. You should set both query_cache_type = OFF and query_cache_size = 0 . There is (according to a rumor) a 'bug' in the QC code that leaves some code on unless you turn off both of those settings.

VSClasses.inc.256 Error with eval('((1048576 - 1031304) / 0) / 4096') expr=[[((query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache) / query_cache_min_res_unit]]
VSClasses.inc.256 Error with eval('(1048576 - 1031304) / 0 / 16384') expr=[[(query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache / query_alloc_block_size]]
VSClasses.inc.256 Error with eval('0/0') expr=[[Innodb_dblwr_pages_written/Innodb_pages_written]]
VSClasses.inc.256 Error with eval('0 / (0 + 0 + 0)') expr=[[Qcache_hits / (Qcache_hits + Qcache_inserts + Qcache_not_cached)]]
VSClasses.inc.256 Error with eval('0/0') expr=[[Qcache_lowmem_prunes/Qcache_inserts]]

**Abnormally small:**

```
Innodb_adaptive_hash_non_hash_searches = 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed / max(Questions, Queries) = 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc = 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc * 16384 / innodb_buffer_pool_size = 0
Innodb_data_writes - Innodb_log_writes - Innodb_dblwr_writes = 6 /HR
Innodb_data_written = 0
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written = 0
Innodb_master_thread_active_loops = 13
Innodb_mem_adaptive_hash = 0
Innodb_pages_written = 0
Memory_used = 0.04%
Memory_used_initial = 15.7MB
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Aria_pagecache_reads = 18 /sec
Aria_pagecache_write_requests = 1180 /sec
Com_show_fields = 14 /sec
Com_stmt_prepare = 23 /sec
Handler_discover = 3 /HR
Handler_read_next = 1805396 /sec
Handler_read_next / Handler_read_key = 121
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty = 77,929
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free = 2.79e+6
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total = 4.15e+6
Innodb_checkpoint_age = 2.3e+9
Innodb_log_writes / Innodb_log_write_requests = 6636.2%
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs = 55 /sec
Innodb_rows_read = 2894484 /sec
Open_streams = 4
Opened_views = 0.058 /sec
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost = 6
Rows_read = 2887256 /sec
Select_full_range_join = 0.4 /sec
Select_full_range_join / Com_select = 0.18%
Slaves_connected = 0.037 /HR
Threads_cached = 113
performance_schema_max_statement_classes = 222
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
Slave_heartbeat_period = 0
Slave_received_heartbeats = 0
aria_recover_options = BACKUP,QUICK
binlog_row_metadata = NO_LOG
character_set_system = utf8mb3
disconnect_on_expired_password = OFF
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
log_slow_admin_statements = ON
myisam_stats_method = NULLS_UNEQUAL
old_alter_table = DEFAULT
old_mode = UTF8_IS_UTF8MB3
optimizer_trace = enabled=off
slave_parallel_mode = optimistic
sql_slave_skip_counter = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server provisioning is fine. If anything, it's overprovisioned for your site.

If I understand your comments correctly, you have many occurrences of this offending `SELECT distinct wp_usermeta.meta_key FROM wp_usermeta` query. And it seems like that query generates a 172K row result set. Yet you say each user has the entirely reasonable number of 49 rows in wp_usermeta.

So, as @RickJames pointed out, it looks like each user somehow gets their own personal unique `wp_usermeta.meta_key` value. WordPress core doesn't do that and would never do that. The point of those `wp_whatevermeta` tables is to have a limited number of keys.  Also, rerunning that particular query very often is grossly inefficient. What conceivable purpose, other than some global list of users, does that query serve?  So **a plugin** is surely implicated in this. If you can get the Query Monitor (https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin to work, it will tell you what software generated the offending query.

There's nothing magic about queries without `WHERE` clauses. SELECTs like `COUNT(*)` and `DISTINCT`  generally need to scan through an entire table or index to generate their results, so when a table is large the query takes a long time. If you have an index on `wp_usermeta.meta_key`, and it indexes the whole column not the 191 prefix, the offending query should do a relatively inexpensive loose index scan.  But still, it has to do the index scan.

And, try the plugin Rick James and I put together.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/ It makes useful indexes, and also has a couple of diagnostic tools built in.